# IF logic with HTML / JavaScript

Tags: html, if-statement, logic

I am trying to figure out how to code the following logic in html.

- If today's date is Wednesday to Sunday, then the text output should be "1"
- If today's date = Monday, output = "2"
- If today's date = Tuesday, output = "3"

This is how far I got, but I am once again stuck.

Thank you for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="dayofarrival"></p>

<script>
function eta() {
    var eta;
    var day = dayofweek();
    if (day = "Monday") {
        eta = "2";
    } else if (day = "Tuesday") {
        eta = "3";
    } else {
        eta = "1";
    }
document.getElementById("dayofarrival").innerHTML = eta;
}

function dayofweek() {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look for tutorials. You will find a lot of them.

Comment: If you want to use just html look into this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways of solving this.

First, you can use client-side [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/).  For your purposes, this is probably the simplest approach.

Secondly, you could use [server-side code that generates the html](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143194/what-advantages-are-conferred-by-using-server-side-page-rendering) to apply the logic on the server so that the final html is as you desire.  For that, you need to look in to [C#/MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in) Framework, [PHP](http://php.net/), or a host of other solutions.

Comment: Why can't he just use HTML5 output?

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a shot with JavaScript, still stuck though :-(

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to `stackoverflow`. It is always good to ask questions , However in your case if you are learning html you will be learning php soon.Here is a quick way to do it in php , very simple.

```
<?php    
if(date('l')=="Monday"){
    echo "2";
}
else if(date('l')=="Tuesday"){
    echo "3";
}
else {
    echo "1";
}    
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am limited to front end, unfortunately! JavaScript it is..